# MVC4's mapRoute URL -- {controller}/{action} vs Controller/{action}. What's the difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I recently got burned by the fact that these two MVC4 routes, apparently, function differently. I was wondering if someone could highlight what's going on so I could better understand.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "post-User",
    "User",
    new { controller = "User", action = "create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "post-User",
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
    );
```

I thought that the {controller} bit was a placeholder and that saying controller = "User" in the next line would make these two statements equivilant. Apparently using {controller} sets up defaults for all routes?

Comment: I think the first one requires you to specify "User" in your path  and the second substitute a default controller "User" if none was specified

Comment: That's about what I thought, too, but I am specifying a controller in all of my requests and getting different results..

Comment: Are the two routes defined at the same time? If yes, note they have the same key - "post-User"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your belief that the `{controller}` substring acts as a placeholder for a controller name. With that in mind, then, the following route will match *any* controller, but default to the `User` controller where no controller is specified:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "post-User",
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

The following, however, will match the route `User` and - because no controller can be specified - will **always** route to the `User` controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "post-User",
    "User",
    new { controller = "User", action = "create" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

In this instance the difference is meaningless because all you're doing is forcing the route `User` to map to a controller `User`, which is exactly what will happen in your first route anyway.

However, consider the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "post-User",
    "User/{action}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "MyDefaultAction" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "foo",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

Now, your top route will match requests to the `User` controller, with an optional action specified and will default to `MyDefaultAction`. Requests to any *other* controller **will not** match the first route - because the route does not begin with the constant string `User` - and will default back to the second route (foo). Again, the action is optional; however, now, unlike the requests to the `User` controller, your default action for other controllers will be the `Index` action.

So now...

`.../User` defaults to the `MyDefaultAction` action.

`.../SomeOtherController` defaults to the `Index` action.